# How to get Transaction amount from API?

Tags: transactions, operations, java-sdk

I want to display all transactions of given users. Using the Java API, I presume I would do:

```
server.transactions().forAccount(destination2).execute();
```

I would then page through the result. Each item would be a `TransactionResponse` instance. Now from this, one of things I want to retrieve is the amount of the transaction. Yet, I don't see any field that could represent this. Here is a [TransactionResponse.java source code](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/responses/TransactionResponse.java) I looked at.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you should use `server.payments().forAccount(destination2)` (if you want to track only payments) or `server.operations().forAccount(destination2)` (for all operation types) because a transaction itself does not transfer any funds. Think of it as a batch (unit of work) that contains one or more operations.

Read more about [transaction](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html) and [operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/operations.html) concepts.

Comment: Thanks. This is weird. I looked at payments() at it returns OperationResponse object. What I would need is PaymentOperationResponse. However, casting that the result of payments() to PaymentOperationResponse results in ClassCastException. I searched through the java-stellar-sdk and PaymentOperationResponse is used nowehere except for test deserialization classes. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok. Got it. The results of payments() are different types. Some are CreateAccountOperationResponse and others are PaymentOperationResponse. So I have to check each type and figure out what it is and cast accordingly.

Comment: Recent Horizon versions also include `account_merge` operations (`AccountMergeOperationResponse`) in `/payments`.